# Can't install open3d libraries (Error:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d)

Tags: python, open3d

I use pyCharm software in windows 10, and when I tried to install open3d the following error appeared:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for open3d
```

I tried to install it using cmd but the same error appeared, also pip version is 20.1.1.

[image]

Comment: error already existed in my post

Comment: Go to [Getting started — Open3D documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/getting_started.html) and check the [supported Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuqRj.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved: by installing python version 3.77 and run code using it instead of 3.8

Answer (score 4):

If you can't seem to upgrade open3d to version 0.13.0;

Upgrade to the latest pip version

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
sudo pip3 install open3d==0.13.0
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

[Update] `pip install open3d` will work with python version '3.10.x.' In my case I was receiving the same error for python version '3.12.x'. So using a virtual environment with a python version 3.10.x is the best option.
Use: `path\to\python3.10.exe -m venv virtual-env-name`